# What does !!0 refer to when I get a "MissingMethodException" error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exception, eazfuscator

I'm helping my company upgrade from VS 2008 to VS 2010. Somewhere in the middle of all the testing, I'm getting a MissingMethodException saying "Method not found: '!!0 (namespace).(etc).(etc).(function(parameter))'."

Does the '!!0' provide any sort of clue that anyone knows of (Google doesn't recognize exclamation points in its searches)?

Obviously, working in VS 2010
VB.Net 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like obfuscation to me.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/eazfuscator-net/K9mrt6-LD84

Comment: Unfortunately, the “eazfuscator-net” google group was removed by its author. :(